# Flexbox - 4 Column Grid last item stretch

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple Flexbox layout as below..

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.item {
  background:teal;
  flex: 1 0 21%; margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 5</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I get the 5th item to only take up 1/4 column? I am trying to create a 4 column grid but when there are less than 4 I get this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the flex grow 1 otherwise they will grow to fill the row:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.item {
  background:teal;
  flex-basis:21%; /* just set the basis and leave grow and shrink as default */
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 5</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `flex: 1 0 21%` essentialy means setting

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 21%;
```

In this way, the `21%`part is actually useless, as you've set it to expand however much it can within it's part of the row (`flex-grow: 1`). To fix it, you just need to set `flex-basis` to whatever percentage, without setting others. Do it by defining `flex-basis: 21%` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a way to set the width, I don't know if this is what you want.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.item {
  background:teal;
  margin:10px;
  width: 21%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 1</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 2</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 3</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 4</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>


  <div class="item">
    <h1>Item 5</h1>
    <p>
      This is some test content
    <p>
  </div>

</div>
```